# Articles not showing on authors' pages (Wordpress)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm having issues displaying authors' respective articles on my website's author pages. Upon clicking on an author's name, their respective author page displays their profile picture, name, and number of articles, but in place of actual article links, it only says "No articles found matching your query." The code I have for my author page is as follows:

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>
    <div class="row top-padding">
        <section class="small-12 medium-8 columns">
            <section id="authorpage" class="authorpage">
                <?php $author = get_user_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 
    'author_name' ) ); do_action('thb_author',$author->ID);?>
            </section>
          <?php if (have_posts()) :  while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'inc/poststyles/style2' ); ?>
          <?php endwhile; ?>
          <?php the_posts_pagination(array(
            'prev_text'     => '<span>'.esc_html__( "&larr;", 'goodlife' 
    ).'</span>',
            'next_text'     => '<span>'.esc_html__( "&rarr;", 'goodlife' 
    ).'</span>',
            'mid_size'      => 2
          )); ?>
          <?php else : ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'inc/loop/notfound' ); ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </section>
        <?php get_sidebar('author'); ?>
    </div>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Any and all input on what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: can you echo the results of `get_query_var('author_name')` and post it as an edit to your question?

Comment: do you want me to post it in the form of before/after screenshots?

Comment: Just copy/paste the text